What is the maximum amount of energy one electron can have?
Is there any limit on the amount of energy one free electron can have?? Certainly there should be a limit. I think High Energy Physics should be able to answer it. Please somebody help.

Why should there be a limit?

Certainly there should be and why do you think this needs to be a certainty? An electron traveling arbitrarily close to the speed of light can have arbitrarily high kinetic energy in that frame.

Is this electron travelling through an ideal vacuum? At high energy, even photons will affect the electron. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greisen%E2%80%93Zatsepin%E2%80%93Kuzmin_limit

The question needs clarity: are you talking about an electron in a lab, or an electron from some astrophysical process, in the source frame? Or an electron on your charged cat viewed from a frame boosted to $\log_{10}{\gamma} \approx {\rm Tree(3)}$?...b/c that's an energetic electron.

@PM2Ring points out something interesting - given that the CMB exists there might be some upper limit that it gets exponentially harder to push past because even ultra-low-energy photons begin to slow down the electron. I don't have the expertise to do the calculations myself, but I'd imagine that that upper limit is close enough to the Planck scale that it doesn't matter. We still do see things above the GZK cutoff though, like the OMG particle ...

I was studying about the Heisenberg's explaination of why an electron can not be present inside a nucleus i.e. the stability of an atom, let say for an electron inside the nucleus delta r = 10^-15, using heisenberg uncertainty principle and Einstein's energy momentum relation, we get E(min) = 10MeV, So if an electron can have this much of energy it can very much fall into the nucleus. Leads to unstability of an atom. @JonCuster

@Subhu Any s orbital electron has a non-zero probability of being found in the nucleus, but it doesn't spend much time there.

10MeV electrons are not hard to make at all these days. And hitting nuclei with them doesn't really do very much except makes lots of bremsstrahlung.

As far as energies that can be explored with accelerators that work with electrons go (~90 gigaelectron volts in opposing collisions), we have found no "physics" limit to the energies to which electrons can be boosted.
The limits instead are financial. High energies mean enormously expensive equipment- so much so that today, the cost of building big accelerators has to be shared among numerous nations.

I was studying about the Heisenberg's explaination of why an electron can not be present inside a nucleus i.e. the stability of an atom, let say for an electron inside the nucleus delta r = 10^-15, using heisenberg uncertainty principle and Einstein's energy momentum relation, we get E(min) = 10MeV, So if an electron can have this much of energy it can very much fall into the nucleus. Leads to unstability of an atom.

Heisenberg's analysis is wrong in this regard. there is a nonzero probability that you will indeed find an electron inside a nucleus. This occasionally leads to a nuclear reaction called electron capture.
